# How to use icacls in batch file to change ACL's in folder structure

Tags: acl

I would like to write a batch file to change ACL's in certain folder structure on a Windows Server.

Vendor number (100000 till 102000)

- Download -> Read only
- Share -> Read + write but NOT delete

The vendor numbers start from 100000 up to 102000 so this will need a loop.
How can I create this batch using icacls (or cacls) please?

Comment: *How can I create this batch using icacls (or cacls) please?* Study CMD32's documentation, look at a lot of examples, try to understand how it works, and if you then still run into problems, you might be interested in reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Binarus you're right, It's not that hard actually.

This is what I came up with:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (100000,1,1002000) DO (
icacls %%i\Download /grant:r <username>:R 
icacls %%i\Share /grant:r <username>:R /grant <username>:W /deny <username>:D
    )
```